# Interfaces usage

Tags: java, interface

Can you have a class which implements an interface, and choose whether to use the methods in the interface during instantiation of this class? Therefore having object A which uses the interface and object B which does not use it.

Thanks

**Updated:**

Assuming you have a Professor class and this class implements an interface called Employer, which has employ(rAssist x) abstract method.

Now I want to instantiated 2 objects from the Professor class implementing this interface Object A - Professor **can** employ a research assistant and Object B - Professor **cannot employ** research assistants.

Comment: I think You need to clarify your question? What Do you want to say?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The interface methods are only declarations. You can't 'use' them in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ***Can you have a class which implements an interface, and choose whether to use the methods in the interface during instantiation of this class?***

No, if class `C` implements the interface, then all instances of `C` will provide the methods declared in the interface.

What you can do is something like

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    void interfaceMethod() {
        System.out.println("Interface method");
    }
}
```

and then do

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();

MyClass y = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    void interfaceMethod() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
```

In effect, `x` supports the use of `interfaceMethod` while `y` does not. Note however that...

- The usage of `y.interfaceMethod` is not prevented at *compile-time*, i.e. it will not be enforced by the type system.
- With this solution, you are in fact creating an (anonymous) *subclass* of `MyClass` and assigning an instance of it to `y`.

Comment: Ok I understand.  Now from a coder's point of view is this a neat solution?  I am asking cause I need to understand this entirely.

Comment: Naah, you would typically want to program in a way such that errors are caught at compile-time, not at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want class A and Class B to implement a common Interface but you dont want to implement all methods in Class B?

An Interface in simple terms means it is sort of a contract and all the classes which implement it should follow that contract.So if you want Class B to implement the interface , Class B should also follow the same contract. But if you dont want to implement any methos you can always do this.

```
class ISampleInterface {

  void sampleMethod();

  void optionalMethod();

} 

Class A implements ISampleInterface {

    void sampleMethod() {
      //Your Implementation
    }

    void optionalMethod() {
      //Your Implementation
    }
}



class B implements ISampleInterface {

    void sampleMethod() {
      //Your Implementation
    }

    void optionalMethod() {
      throw new UnsupportedMethodException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the point of an `Interface`.

An `Interface` is contract that guarantees that implementations WILL implement it's signature

Comment: I believe that doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Habib Hay, I'm half a sleep, so I'd appreciate if you could help and explain what I missed :P

Comment: see the answer of aioobe, What you are saying is perfectly right with respect to interfaces, but OP is asking about objects of a same class using methods from interface based on some condition

Comment: @Habib Ah, okay, obviously need more sleep, thanks for taking the time to point it out, much appreciated :) - Yes, I thought aioode's answer was much better as well

Answer (score 0):

The idea of interface is to establish a obligation for the class that implements the interface.
If your's is a requirement, you can use the java.lang.reflect.Method reflection class to change the visibility of the method at runtime. However, this is not a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Interfaces` were introduced in Java because **Multiple Inheritance was not allowed** in Java.

**2.** But as far as `Design Pattern` are concerned, following are the uses..

**-**  To `implement certain Roles`.

Consider **Dog** a **Super class**, but then **Pet dog and Wild dog can be interfaces, which
    can be implemented by the Sub Classes of Dog class.**

**-**  Used when `Behaviors keeps changing`.

Consider you have a **Class Drawing**, and **paint method() in it**, now paint can be stroking, shading, etc...
You must **Encapsulate such behaviors in an Interface or an Abstract class.**

Comment: Thanks for the examples...helpful.